# How can I responsive between panel and flowlayoutpanel in c#

Tags: c#

I created a window containing 1 flowlayoutpanel and panel.
When I enlarge the size of the window, the flowlayoutpanel changes with the window but the panel doesn't change with the flowlayoutpanel.
I'm having a problem that the panel doesn't automatically adjust its size when resize flowlayoutpanel.

this is code :

```
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.pnl_1);
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.TopDown;
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.Name = "flowLayoutPanel1";
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(666, 545);
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 1;
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.WrapContents = false;
    // 
    // pnl_1
    // 
    this.pnl_1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
    this.pnl_1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Azure;
    this.pnl_1.Controls.Add(this.txt_input1_3);
    this.pnl_1.Controls.Add(this.txt_associated1_3);
    this.pnl_1.Controls.Add(this.txt_input1_2);
    this.pnl_1.Controls.Add(this.txt_input1_1);
    this.pnl_1.Controls.Add(this.txt_associated1_2);
    this.pnl_1.Controls.Add(this.txt_associated1_1);
    this.pnl_1.Controls.Add(this.txt_field_1);
    this.pnl_1.Controls.Add(this.lb_field1);
    this.pnl_1.Controls.Add(this.lb_input1);
    this.pnl_1.Controls.Add(this.lb_associal1);
    this.pnl_1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
    this.pnl_1.Name = "pnl_1";
    this.pnl_1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(663, 113);
    this.pnl_1.TabIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Read the docs carefully - it's an odd control - you might get a clue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-anchor-and-dock-child-controls-in-a-flowlayoutpanel-control

Comment: when i maximizine the window, the flowlayoutpanel enlarges but the panel and buttons in the flowlayoutpanel do not change in size

Comment: Yes, I understand your question. Did you read the docs?